# Saber quais checkboxs estão selecionadas no adapter e fazer operações na activity baseado nas checks selecionadas

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-adapter

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Olá, eu tenho uma lista (ListView) e quando eu seleciono a opção 1 no meu spinner ele da visible no framelayout para mostrar na tela uma checkbox para cadad item da lista com status 0p, eu queria saber quais checksboxs estão selecionadas no adapter para que na activity eu possa incluir numa lista e mudar status.
Esta é minha activity:

```
spinnerSync.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,  final int position, long id) {

            //Guardo na variavel estatica para no adapter fazer a verificação se mostra ou não a check
            POSITION=position;
                //Cria a lista na activity
                adapter2= new SyncAdapter2(listaForm, getApplicationContext());
                listView.setAdapter(adapter2);



                buttonSync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Verificar quais itens da listView estão checkados(checkbox)
                        // Pegar a posição dos itens checkado

                        //inclui form no SQLite e consequentemente na lista agenda
                        if (listaForm.get(position).getStatus()==0) {
                            dao.incluir(listaForm);
                        }


                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(
                                new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }, 3000L);
                        load.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

E este meu adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.sinc_item_listview2, null);

    checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

    checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (SincActivity.POSITION == 1) {

        if (listForm.get(position).getStatus() != 1)
            checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TextView tvDayNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDayNumber);
            tvDayNumber.setText(listForm.get(position).getDataForm());
            tvDayNumber.setTypeface(tf);
            TextView tvDayWeek = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDayWeek);
            tvDayWeek.setText(listForm.get(position).getDataForm());
            tvDayWeek.setTypeface(tf);
            TextView tvLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
            tvLocation.setText("#" + listForm.get(position).getNomeLoja());
            tvLocation.setTypeface(tf);
            TextView tvHour = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvHour);
            tvHour.setText(listForm.get(position).getHora() + " | ");
            tvHour.setTypeface(tf);
            TextView tvForms = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvForm);
            tvForms.setText(listForm.get(position).getNomeFom());
            tvForms.setTypeface(tf);

            ImageView imageInfo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageInfo);
            if (listForm.get(position).getStatus() == 1) {
                imageInfo.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
            } else {
                imageInfo.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation);
            }
    } else {
        TextView tvDayNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDayNumber);
        tvDayNumber.setText(listForm.get(position).getDataForm());
        tvDayNumber.setTypeface(tf);
        TextView tvDayWeek = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDayWeek);
        tvDayWeek.setText(listForm.get(position).getDataForm());
        tvDayWeek.setTypeface(tf);
        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
        tvLocation.setText("#" + listForm.get(position).getNomeLoja());
        tvLocation.setTypeface(tf);
        TextView tvHour = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvHour);
        tvHour.setText(listForm.get(position).getHora() + " | ");
        tvHour.setTypeface(tf);
        TextView tvForms = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvForm);
        tvForms.setText(listForm.get(position).getNomeFom());
        tvForms.setTypeface(tf);

        ImageView imageInfo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageInfo);
        if (listForm.get(position).getStatus() == 1) {
            imageInfo.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);
        } else {
            imageInfo.setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation);
        }
    }



    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Checkado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.w("id",position+"");
                listaInteger.add(listForm.get(position).getIdForm());

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context,"uncheck",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.w("id",position+"");
                listaInteger.remove(listForm.get(listForm.get(position).getIdForm()).getIdForm());
            }
        }
    });


    v.setTag(listForm.get(position).getIdForm());

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o que realmente você quer fazer.

Acho que com getAdapter() seja possível resolver isso, se entendi. 

Ponha um print, pois não conseguir imaginar a tela.

Comment: coloquei o print